# How to remove these "scratches" from Teak Hardwood

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor

Any ideas how I could go about fixing these "scratches"? I believe these were made by a heavy suitcase. The wood is solid teak hardwood. The surface feels smooth, except for the gouges. The polyurethane looks clouded, or possibly separated from the wood underneath. I'm not sure what the damage is, but it doesn't look like a typical scratch.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what's a `typical scratch`?

Comment: I mean it’s not typical because it still feels smooth, there’s no divot or indentation, except for the gouges at the start.

Comment: The finish is not well bonded, probably because of the oil in the teak (should have been wiped with acetone to clear the oil before finish imo) We don't know what finish was used, so fixing may be problematic. If you put a little acetone (in non-visible area) and the finish melts, then its wax,oil, or varnish and you can lightly sand, clean, and patch. If it is a harder finish, like a cross-hatch, its a redo. A patch is likely to show, particularly if not the same finish. Test well before committing.

Comment: @Jack it looks like it's the polyurethane that is scratched and is peeling where the scratches are

Comment: I applied Acetone to an old scrap piece and had no effect. Tried applying with a towel and poured some directly on the surface and let it sit a minute. No different, it wiped right off and the surface looked no different.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how good a match and how good a finish you are after.

1. You could put a damp rag on portions of the scratch and iron it or give the wood bursts of steam.  This may marge the scratch somewhat.  Then try and match the coating
2. Or for best finish, you may need to sand off the entire floor and recoat.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't look like wood, it looks like 'plastic' or melamine veneer. You can see areas it's been gouged through to the substrate, and there is no grain marking in the lighter scratches.

[image]

The only 'fix' for that would be to see if some wax 'repair' pencils could disguise it a bit.

[image]

Comment: The product is Bellawood 3/4” solid Teak purchased at Lumber Liquidators about 12 years ago. I can’t find it online anymore, this wood may be discontinued or sold under a different name.

Comment: Then try sanding a small area.